# sysibmadm.raise_application_error_2 and packages and user permisions

Tags: windows, db2, db2-luw

I have to remove the login of my predecessor from DB2 LUW V10.1 on Windows.  I was able to remove from all except for some Packages of SYSIBMADM schema for which it is giving the below error. This is the statement that is erroring out on:

```
REVOKE BIND, EXECUTE, CONTROL ON PACKAGE SYSIBMADM.P9054818 FROM USER JJOHN
```

> ERROR [42893] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0478N  The statement failed because one or more dependencies exist on the target object. Target object type: "PACKAGE". Name of an object that is dependent on the target object: "SYSIBMADM.RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR_2". Type of object that is dependent on the target object: "PROCEDURE".

I have to remove the login for audit purposes. Does anyone have any idea or point me in the right direction?

```
SET CURRENT SCHEMA = SYSIBM;

SET CURRENT PATH = SYSIBM,SYSFUN,SYSPROC,SYSIBMADM;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYSIBMADM.RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
    IN NUM  INTEGER,
    IN MSG  VARCHAR(2000),
    IN KEEPERRORSTACK   BOOLEAN )
  SPECIFIC RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR_2
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  EXTERNAL ACTION
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
BEGIN
     IF keeperrorstack IS NULL OR keeperrorstack = true THEN            
        CALL SYSIBMINTERNAL.SQLEML_RAISE_ERROR( -171, '3', 'RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR', 'KEEPERRORSTACK' );
     END IF;
     CALL SYSIBMADM.RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( num, msg );
END;

GRANT EXECUTE ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE SYSIBMADM.RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR_2 TO PUBLIC WITH GRANT OPTION;

SET CURRENT SCHEMA = RGN;
```

Comment: My first guess would be your attempt to (potentially) assign in the callee (via INOUT parameters) values to non-assignable IN parameters in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The error informs you that there is a `PROCEDURE` `SYSIBMADM.RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR_2` which depends on this package, and you should revoke the corresponding privileges namely from this procedure rather than from the package.
So, in you case you should revoke the `execute` privilege from this user on the routine returned by the following query (should return "SYSIBMADM"."RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR_2"):

```
select '"'||routineschema||'"."'||specificname||'"'  
from syscat.routinedep 
where 
--routineschema='SYSIBMADM' and specificname='RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR_2'
bschema='SYSIBMADM' and bname='P9054818'
and btype='K';
```

Comment: When I run the below command 

"REVOKE EXECUTE ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE SYSIBMADM.RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR_2 FROM USER JJOHN RESTRICT;"



I get the below error

"An attempt to revoke a privilege, security label, exemption, or role from "JJOHN" was denied because "JJOHN" does not hold this privilege, security label, exemption, or role."

Comment: This means, that you shouldn't run any statements against both objects for this user.